# Compare 2 arrays of First and Last Names

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to compare queries from two SQL databases (personnel database & call manager database) to find DNs (personal extensions) that have employees who have left the company.

The problem is, the personnel database first names alternate between 'Given Name' and 'Nick Name'. I thought I could have the databases match on the 'Last Name' (since that doesn't change) and then use a regex pattern to match the first two characters of the first name so that it'll match most Given and Nick Names (e.g. Joseph and Joe).

I'm just confused on where to implement the regex. Below is how I usually use nested loops.

```
$match = @()
$nomatch = @()

foreach ($cucm in $cucmresults)
{
    $foundMatch = $false

    foreach ($coco in $cocoresults)
    {
        if (($cucm.LastName) -eq $coco.LastName)
        {           
            if (($cucm.firstName -eq $coco.FirstName) -or 
                     ($cucm.firstName) -eq ($coco.Nickname))
            {
                $match += $cucm
                $foundMatch = $true
                break
            }
        }      
    }    
    if ($foundMatch -eq $false)
    {    
       $nomatch += $cucm
    }
}

Here is sample data:
$cucmresults:

Extension     FirstName     LastName
1000          Daniel        Johnson
1001          Joe           Smith
1002          Wing Lok      Lu

$cocoresults:
Extension     FirstName    NickName      LastName
1000          Daniel       Dan           Johnson
1001          Joe          Joe           Smith
1002          Wing Lok     Wing Lok      Lu
```

Basically, I'd like 100% match LastName as it is always static. FirstName  alternates between their full name and nick name. I'd like to use a regex 
expression to match the "Da" in Dan under FirsName once LastName matches.

Comment: Can you provide sample records of `cucmresults` and `cocoresults` including the desired result?

Comment: @sdcrytek You'll need to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43324307/edit) your question to include more information as comments aren't suitable for this.